# Python: uniqe integer for dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have the following data class.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class myDataClass:
    x: float
    y: float
```

What I want is that every time I create an object of this class, it gets labeled with a unique id which increments from 0.

So, the first time I say `first = myDataClass(0, 1)` then I should have `first.id == 0`, and then if I say `second = myDataClass(0, 1)`, I should get `second.id == 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A thread-safe unique ID can be generated by using [an `itertools.count()` instance's `__next__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) as the `default_factory` for the field:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from itertools import count

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class myDataClass:
    x: float
    y: float
    id: int = field(default_factory=count().__next__, init=False)
```

It's faster than other options, involves no custom code, and, at least on the CPython reference interpreter, is thread-safe (`itertools.count` is implemented in C and does not release the GIL, so there's no chance of two instances getting the same `id`).

Comment: ohh, that's really neat.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tricky for frozen dataclasses because any code that you write which dynamically updates a field runs into a `FrozenInstanceError`, but it's certainly possible:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class myDataClass:
    x: float
    y: float
    id: int = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not hasattr(myDataClass, "_COUNT"):
            myDataClass._COUNT = 0
        object.__setattr__(self, "id", myDataClass._COUNT)
        myDataClass._COUNT += 1
```

Which should work as you expected:

```py
>>> (myDataClass(1.0,2.0))
myDataClass(x=1.0, y=2.0, id=0)
>>> (myDataClass(1.0,2.0))
myDataClass(x=1.0, y=2.0, id=1)
>>> (myDataClass(1.0,2.0))
myDataClass(x=1.0, y=2.0, id=2)
>>> (myDataClass(1.0,2.0))
myDataClass(x=1.0, y=2.0, id=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default_factory` for attributes of dataclasses that function like you want, and use a class variable to keep track of the maximum id used.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import ClassVar


def _assign_id():
    new_id = myDataClass._next_id
    myDataClass._next_id += 1
    return new_id


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class myDataClass:
    x: float
    y: float
    id: int = field(default_factory=_assign_id, init=False)
    _next_id: ClassVar[int] = 0
```